# Regex to match a fragment of the URL

Tags: c#, regex

I have URL's like:

http://127.0.0.1:81/controller/verbOne/**NXw4fDF8MXwxfDQ1**?source=dddd

or

http://127.0.0.1:81/controller/verbTwo/**NXw4fDF8MXwxfDQ1**

I'd like to extract that part in bold. The host and port can change to anything (when I publish it to a live server it will change). The controller never changes. And for the verb part, there are 2 possibilities.

Can anyone help me with the regex?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a regex you could use the built in functionality of `Uri`

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:81/controller/verbOne/NXw4fDF8MXwxfDQ1?source=dddd");

var lastSegment = uri.Segments.Last();
```

Comment: @L.B It seems like he said he wanted to _extract_ the part in bold - `verbOne` and `verbTwo` are not in bold, are they? (there are merely two possibilities of what they could be)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `Uri` and `Path` classes:

```
Path.GetFileName(new Uri(str).AbsolutePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you look for a regex? you can look for the two string elements "verbOne/" or "verbTwo/" and make a substring from the end. And then you can look for the rest and substrakt the part with the '?'

I think this is faster then a regex.

krikit

Answer (score 0):

Though everyone else here is correct that regex is not the best solution, because it could fail when parsers already exist that should never fail due to their specialization, I believe you *could* use the following regex:

```
(?<=http://127\.0\.0\.1:81/controller/verb(One|Two)/)[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```